# geom_line only connects points on horizontal lines instead all points

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I've written something in R using ggplot2 and don't know why it behaves as it does.

If I plot my data using `geom_point` and `geom_line` it is supposed to draw lines trough those points. but instead of connecting all the points it only connects those that are on a horizontal line. I don't know how to handle this.

This is a simple version of the code:

```
date<-c("2014-07-01","2014-07-02","2014-07-03",
    "2014-07-04","2014-07-05","2014-07-06",
    "2014-07-07")
mbR<- c(160,163,169,169,169,169,169)
mbL<-     c(166,166,166,166,NA, NA, NA)
mb<-data.frame(mbR,mbL)
mb<-data.frame(t(as.Date(date)),mb)
colnames(mb)<-c("Datum","R","L")
mb$Datum<-date

plot1<-ggplot(mb,aes(x=mb$Datum,y=mb$R))+
geom_point(data=mb,aes(x=mb$Datum,y=mb$R,color="R",size=2),
           group=mb$R,position="dodge")+
geom_line(data=mb,aes(y=mb$R,color="R",group=mb$R))+
geom_point(aes(y=mb$L,color="L",size=2),position="dodge")

plot1
```

I used group, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to draw any lines, still it doesn't do what I intended.

I hope you guys can help me out a little. :) It may be a minor fault.

Comment: Of possible relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617629/connecting-across-missing-values-with-geom-line

Answer (score 4):

First, melt your data to long format and then plot it. The column called `variable` in the melted data is the category (`R` or `L`). The column called `value` stores the data values for each instance of `R` and `L`. We group and color the data by `variable` in the call to `ggplot`, which gives us separate lines/points for `R` and `L`.

Also, you only need to provide the data frame and column mappings in the initial call to `ggplot`. They will carry through to `geom_point` and `geom_line`. Furthermore, when you provide the column names, you don't need to (and shouldn't) include the name of the data frame, because you've already specified the data frame in the `data` argument to `ggplot`.

```
library(reshape2)
mb.l = melt(mb, id.var="Datum")

ggplot(data=mb.l, aes(x=Datum, y=value, group=variable, color=variable)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks i didnt know about melting
this helped me out quite fast :)