# connect points across selected NAs with geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question is closely related to [Connecting across missing values with geom_line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617629/connecting-across-missing-values-with-geom-line), but it's a follow-up rather than a duplicate.

I have data with missing values NA. The data has been 'melted' in long form with package `reshape2` and I am using `ggplot2` to plot both `geom_points()` and `geom_line()`. In the example data, I have one group only, in my real data I have several groups. I would like to plot a `geom_line()` connecting data points that are not separated by more than 4 years of missing data. In other words, if there are 3 adjacent rows with NA, apply `na.rm` to the data.frame, while if there are at least 4 adjacent rows with NA, do not apply `na.rm` to the data.frame.

Edit: Note: I am replicating figures from a book, where the points are connected even when the data is missing. It would be better to use a different `linetype` or `colour` for those segments connecting missing data, together with a note in the legend explaining it.

In the following, I have a very tedious and ugly hack that will not scale up to manipulating large amounts of data. I'd be grateful for a simpler approach and particularly keen to find a simple way to count instances of consecutive NAs in the data.

```
### ggplot draws geom_line with NAs

# Data (real-world example, so not exactly MWE)
df <- 
structure(list(Year = c(1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 
1917, 1918, 1919, 1920, 1921, 1922, 1923, 1924, 1925, 1926, 1927, 
1928, 1929, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 
1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 
1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 
1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 
1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 
1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 
1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010), variable = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("France", "Germany", "Sweden", "Japan"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), value = c(0.1724, 0.1748, 
0.1752, 0.1777, 0.1778, 0.1953, 0.2132, 0.2242, 0.222, 0.1947, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.113, 0.113, 0.115, 0.112, 0.111, NA, NA, 
0.114, 0.109, 0.113, 0.12, 0.137, 0.15, 0.163, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.116, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.11, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.122, NA, NA, NA, 0.122, NA, NA, 0.112, NA, NA, 
0.113, NA, NA, 0.101, NA, NA, 0.102, NA, NA, 0.1043, NA, NA, 
0.0906, NA, NA, 0.0964, NA, NA, 0.1052, NA, NA, 0.1043, NA, NA, 
0.1005, NA, NA, 0.1088, NA, NA, 0.101139312657167, 0.0950290025146689, 
0.0901042749371333, 0.09, 0.107249622799665, 0.108891198658843, 
0.115913495389774, 0.110684772282761, 0.113299133836267, 0.111991953059514
)), .Names = c("Year", "variable", "value"), row.names = 102:202, class = "data.frame")
```

The default plot:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = value, group = variable, colour = variable, shape = variable)) + 
    geom_point(size = 3) + geom_line()
```

[image]

The plot with all NAs removed (see [Connecting across missing values with geom_line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617629/connecting-across-missing-values-with-geom-line)):

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = value, group = variable, colour = variable, shape = variable)) + 
    geom_point(size = 3) + geom_line(data = df[!is.na(df$value), ])
```

[image]

The desired plot:

```
df2 <- df
df2[df2$Year == 1922, ]$value <- "-999999"
df2[df2$Year == 1948, ]$value <- "-999999"
df2 <- df2[!is.na(df2$value), ]
df2$value <- as.numeric(df2$value)
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Year, y = value, group = variable, colour = variable, shape = variable)) + geom_point(size = 3) + 
    geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(limit = c(.08, .23))
```

[image]

Comment: Your desired plot is not consistent with hour rules. The point at 1950 should be isolated, as the years 1939 - 1949 are `NA`, as are the years 1951 - 1956. Both are sequences of >3 `NA`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This produces your "desired plot", with the exception noted in the comment.

```
x <- rle(!is.na(df$value))
x$values[which(x$lengths>3 & !x$values)] <- TRUE
indx <- inverse.rle(x)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df[indx,],aes(x=Year,y=value,color=variable))+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Basically, we encode `NA` as `FALSE`, and everything else as `TRUE`, then perform run length encoding to identify sequences of `T/F`. Any sequence of `FALSE` of length > 3 should be kept, so we convert those to `TRUE` (as if they were not `NA`), then we use inverse rle to recover an index vector with `TRUE` if the row should be kept. Finally, we apply this to the `df` for use in `ggplot`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the explanation: I had not heard of the ``rle`` function before, it will be great to have. You're also spot on about my inconsistent verbal description of the selection rules!

Comment: I don't fully understand how, but this works great and I think I get the gist of it. Is there a way to put this into a function that, based on the `data` and `y` input yields the output needed for `geom_line()` to skip `NA`s? Basically, I would like to be able to call `ggplot(function(my.data), aes(x,y)) + geom_line()`. Is there a way?