# How to plot a line plot with NA entries?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting multiple variables at once using `ggplot2` in `R`, how can I omit `NA` entries so that the line graph is connected?

As you can see my dataset is riddled with `NA` entries. (I am using my weightlifting training to learn how to use `R`. As I am not doing the same exercise each workout, I am bound to have `NA` entries.)  I know that I can omit lines with `NA` entries, but that would delete every line in my dataframe.

Is it possible to plot my dataframe as a continous line plot without line breaks?

```
ss <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18421, 18423, 18425, 18428, 
18431, 18435), class = "Date"), bw = c(NA, NA, NA, 95.4, NA, 
NA), squat = c(40, 42.5, 45, 47.5, 50, 52.5), deadlift = c(60, 
NA, 62.5, 65, 67.5, 70), press = c(25, NA, 27.5, NA, 30, NA), 
    bench = c(NA, 40, NA, 42.5, NA, 45), chinup = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), clean = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code I have written so far. First I am trying to clean my data using `tidyverse` . Then I want to plot the dataset in one `ggplot`.

```
ss <- ss %>%
  select(date, bw, squat, deadlift, press, bench, chinup, clean) %>%
  gather(key = "lift", value = "weight", -date, -bw)

ggplot(ss, aes(x = date, y = weight)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = lift)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = lift, linetype = lift))
```

[My plot as of now. Oh the gaps!...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWXS5.png)

Comment: Drop the NAs after gathering, e.g. `filter(!is.na(weight)`

Comment: @stefan That worked, but I had to exclude ```bw``` from the gather as it contained mostly NAs. Thanks you for your help. (Would you like to write an answer or should I answer my question myself?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting across missing values with geom\_line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617629/connecting-across-missing-values-with-geom-line)

Comment: @kaos. Yep. Sorry. The `drop_na` was a bit to radical. Filter is the way to go.

Comment: @stefan Ah, perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @Adam Yes, it seems to do the same thing, although I think stefans answer is easier to understand and uses the coding ansatz I provided. But thank you anyway for your effort!

Comment: @kaos yes his answer is definitely a needed update using `tidyverse` and I prefer it as well. But I think it is useful to link the questions as they ask essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Adam Sure, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply drop the NAs after gathering with `filter(!is.na(weight)`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

ss <- ss %>%
  select(date, bw, squat, deadlift, press, bench, chinup, clean) %>%
  gather(key = "lift", value = "weight", -date, -bw) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(weight))

ggplot(ss, aes(x = date, y = weight)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = lift)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = lift, linetype = lift))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I am using ```R``` for a while now, but only now I realise how much easier everything gets when using piping and the tidyverse.

Answer (score 2):

Probably less clean of an approach, but the lines will be connected on the `x` axis. So you can reverse the x and y in your plot, and then flip the coordinates as well.

```r
ggplot(ss, aes(x = weight, y = date)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = lift)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = lift, linetype = lift)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, too! (I am not allowed to upvote yet, sorry.)